# What is the meaning of the word VISHWA (world) in Hinduism

Tags: india, sati-goddess, geography

Many Hindu scriptures talk about some events which occurred all over the Vishwa or world. Does the world here mean then undivided Bharat (from Afghanistan to Sri Lanka to Myanmar) as there was no trace of Hinduism outside Bharat?
E.g. After the death of sati, lord shiva danced in anger with the dead body of sati all over the world but there are 51 shakti pith only in India, none outside of India.

Comment: Vishwa means the entire Universe including constellations, heavens, other lokas and everything...

Comment: There can be various interpretation, you can take a look at [Sanskrit dictionary](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=विश्व&lang=sans&action=Search)

Comment: depends upon the context it is being used. It can mean the material universe (the seen world) in one context, in another context it means both worlds, both the seen and unseen universes or worlds ( in other words  - it can mean 'all'). It does not refer to just Bharat.

Comment: Swamiji what should be the meaning of world for the example I mentioned in my question?